# Why do we need FPGA and not microcontroller to implement Bitbus protocol?

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, rs485, protocol

I need to design a board with a Bitbus protocol master to interface with other slave devices and was searching for options. All I get is Bitbus protocol IP for FPGAs.

Why can't we implement Bitbus protocol in Microcontroller using software stack? After all it works on RS485 PHY and SDLC logic layer.

Comment: It should be possible with any suitably-fast micro.  [Bus specs here](http://www.bitbus.org/fprimer.htm).  Most likely, there is a market for FPGA IP, and none for micro IP; therefore all you're seeing is FPGA IP.

Comment: theoretically possible with sufficiently fast microcontroller & hardware.  would it be economical compared to an fpga if an fpga is sufficient? you can also theoretically beat fpga in economy with a non programmable gate array if the quantity is high enough...

Comment: Might be one of those jobs that's possible by bit-banging in an MCU, but just massively simpler and easier in an FPGA. It's not got the momentum of I2C, SPI or Ethernet so that  any MCU is sold with a Bitbus interface. (Buy the right FPGA and it'll have an MCU or several built in)

Comment: I don't know anything about Bitbus, but I wonder whether the [FlexIO module](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/supporting-information/FTF-ACC-F1179_Introduction_to_FlexIO.pdf) found in some NXP Microcontrollers could be programmed to do Bitbus?

Comment: I also think, it should be theoretically possible with micro. I will check FlexIO from NXP.

Answer (score 1):

A few decades ago, I implemented Bitbus on an 80188 processor, driving a Zilog Z8530 Serial Communications Controller. The code wasn't very complicated or CPU-intensive, but it heavily relied on the SCC for the low-level encoding - I suspect many of the modern USART serial controllers won't be compatible, because they have simpler synchronous functionality.

Comment: My point is exactly that. The code should not be very complecated. Still there is not a single library available for that. Is it just because of less popularity of the protocol or some technical challenge?